# SQL calling function not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

[image]

When I call my function in a stored procedure like:

```
WHERE AREA IN (dbo.splitstring(@communityDesc))
```

> Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or
>   aggregate "dbo.splitstring", or the name is ambiguous.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `where area in (select name from dbo.splitstring(@communityDesc))`

Comment: Pro-tip. Create a user defined data type and use that.

Comment: For what it is worth, this is a very [inefficient way to split strings](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)